# How to name radio for a list of radio group in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I expect it will send out a list of color. In html, if inputs are list, they should be same name, but same name of radio inputs, they will be in same group, so how to separate each radio group, but all group still have same name, then I can use loop go get all value of the list at server side?

Besides, at client side, I need to check whether each group is selected, so how to use javascript or jquery to select all radio groups, not all radio buttons.

```
<form method="post">
Car A: <input type="radio" name="color[]"/>red <input type="radio" name="color[]"/>yello<br/>
Car B: <input type="radio" name="color[]"/>red <input type="radio" name="color[]"/>yello<br/>
Car C: <input type="radio" name="color[]"/>red <input type="radio" name="color[]"/>yello<br/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: You can't each radio group must used a different name otherwise how do you know when you receive the form which color is for which car.

Comment: You could use php to get the values on input then compare to whatever you are trying to do all on submit of the form. In php this could possibly be turned into an array.

Comment: jQuery is a JavaScript library, not an alternative to JavaScript. The phrase "javascript or jquery" makes no sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each group should have a different name for all of it's radio buttons.

```
Car A: 
<input type="radio" name="color1"/>red 
<input type="radio" name="color1"/>yello<br/>

Car B: 
<input type="radio" name="color2"/>red 
<input type="radio" name="color2"/>yello<br/>

Car C: 
<input type="radio" name="color3"/>red 
<input type="radio" name="color3"/>yello<br/>
```

Checking if all the groups were selected:

```
if ($('input[type="radio"]:checked').length == 3)
    validAction();
else
    invalidAction();
```

You can limit the selector to only elements which their `name` attributes begin with `color`:

```
if ($('input[type="radio"][name^="color"]:checked').length == 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Every member of a group must have the same name. Every group must have a different name.

If you want to pander to PHP's naming conventions for presenting data in a loop then use a convention such as: `group[0]` for the first group then `group[1]` for the second and so on. That gives you unique names on the client while PHP will merge them into an array.

On the client side you can do something along the lines of:

```
var i = 0, myform = /* something */;
while (myform.elements['group[' + i + ']']) {
    var group = myform.elements['group[' + i + ']'];
    /* Loop over HTML Element Collection to make sure one item is `checked`. */
}
```